# How do I do thread-safe python XML validation?

Tags: python, xml, multithreading, validation, lxml

Using Python 3.3, I need to validate XML documents against their DTDs or XSDs, and I expect to validate many documents against each specification.  I will have a multi-threaded application performing the validation.  [lxml documentation](http://lxml.de/validation.html) explains how to validate against each specification type.

Lxml records validation errors in an array on the specification itself, therefore I will need a new copy of the specification for each validation I perform.

It is not possible (thread-safe) to re-parse the DTD specification each time because my DTD includes other files, and I have found it necessary to change directories to the folder containing the DTD files to get lxml to find them.  I cannot do a thread-safe cd, so I read all the specs at application launch.

It is not desirable to re-parse either (XSD or DTD) specification because it takes I/O time and parsing time.

My attempts at copy and deepcopy of the spec (DTD and XMLSchema objects) failed outright.

Is there a way to get lxml to validate safely?  Is there a better library to use that will support both XSD and DTD and let me check errors thread-safe?

Comment: If this is linux, you may be able to create child processes to do the work after the DTD/XSD is loaded. The DTD isn't copied since the child gets a view of the parent's memory but any changes it makes to the DTD aren't seen by the parent.

Comment: That works!  I had to send back the return value through a Pipe.  Thanks.

Comment: Great! I'll turn it into the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On linux, a forked process gets a copy-on-write view of the parent's memory. You can leverage this to process a large object with little overhead and without changing the object in the parent's memory space. After creating the object, create pipes for communication and fork a child to do the work. The `multiprocessing` module's `Process` class can do the heavy lifting for you.